# ReflectionTypeLoadException, DllImport and Generic class

Tags: generics, reflection, pinvoke, mef, dllimport

I try use MEF in my project, but some cases I get this error:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException
```

Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Generic method or method in generic class is internal call, PInvoke, or is defined in a COM Import class.

In log exception it appears a generic class that use DllImport attrib.

is it not possible to call pinvoke methods in a generic class ?

I am still interested why this causes a problem.

source code:

```
void Compose()
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryCatalog catalog =
                    new DirectoryCatalog(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

                AggregateCatalog agcatalogue = new AggregateCatalog(new ComposablePartCatalog[] {catalog, 
                    new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())});

                CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(agcatalogue);

                CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();

                batch.AddPart(this);

                container.Compose(batch);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fnfex.Message);
            }
            catch (CompositionException cex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cex.Message);
            }
            catch (System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException rte)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rte.Message);
                foreach (Exception ex in rte.LoaderExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }


//Generic Class
 [Serializable]
    public class ProcessCounters<T> : IDisposable where T : ICounterData
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Extern
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ticks"></param>
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern void QueryPerformanceCounter(ref long ticks);

        private static T _counterData;

...}
```

**Update:**
Limitation: You can't have DllImports in a generic class.  Put your DllImports in a 
separate, static, class (as recommended).
Solution: Solved it by moving the NativeMethods class outside of the generic class.

http://blog.appelgren.org/2006/05/04/nested-class-with-pinvoke-in-generic-class/

http://www.archivum.info/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.clr/2006-12/00015/RE-TypeLoadException-when-instantiating-generic-class-that-uses-D.html

Comment: What is the type that `Compose` belongs to? You're composing something but we have no idea what... Also, the generic type `ProcessCounters<T>` is not exported.

Comment: Limitation: You can't have DllImports in a generic class.